# I can't get Google Analytics 4 (GA4) .net client library to work on a .net framework 4.7.2 project

Tags: .net, google-analytics-4

When trying to install Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta using NuGet the package fails to install

> Install failed. Rolling back...
> Could not install package 'Grpc.Net.Client 2.46.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

It looks like one of its dependencies does not support .Net Framework

However looking at : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta#supportedframeworks-body-tab
it shows that Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta supports net462 and higher

Anyone was able to install the .Net client library for a .net Framework 4.7.2 project?

Answer (score 0):

This page talks about an http2 requirement, and some alternatives.

```
.NET Framework has limited support for gRPC over HTTP/2. To enable gRPC over HTTP/2 on .NET Framework, configure the channel to use WinHttpHandler.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-7.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue while installing Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta using NuGet in VS2015, but when I tried to install in different VS version eg:2017,2019,2022, it got successfully installed. So, I guess the issue is not about the framework version that we are using but about VS version.
[VS Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph27M.png)